# Nested call for brackets

Tags: macros, brackets

I need to create a custom command that behaves differently when it is called.
For example consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bkt}[1]{\left( {#1} \right)}
\begin{document}
    $\bkt{\bkt{\bkt{1+2} + \bkt{3+4}}-9}$
\end{document}
```

I obtain (((1 + 2) + (3 + 4)) − 9). I would like to define the command bkt that gives me automatically {[(1 + 2) + (3 + 4)] − 9}.

Finally it should also consider the following case: {[((1))]}, i.e. when the brackets root in deep then 3.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using `\left/right` in this case as they too often becomes too large when used within `$...$`. You will probably need to preprocess the argument for the macro in order to know which level the outer most brackets should be.

Answer (score 5):

Then you are probably interested in the »[bropd](http://ctan.org/pkg/bropd)« package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bropd}

\begin{document}
  $\br{\br{\br{1+2} + \br{3+4}}-9}$
\end{document}
```

The package has some more capabilities than only this one.

---

[image]

Comment: @Alessio: If this answer led you to the solution, there's not problem if you [accept it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).